# Do enchantments attached to Bruna, Light of Alabaster trigger on the same attack/block instance?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Question 1:

1. I have [Bruna](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=451125) on the field, and I attack, triggering her effect.
2. I attach [Ordeal of Thassa](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373696) using her effect.

I am inclined to conclude that Ordeal's effect doesn't trigger during this combat phase, because the attack has already taken place before it was on the battlefield. Is this correct?

Question 2:

1. I have Bruna on the field, and I block one of multiple attacking creatures, triggering her effect.
2. I attach [Iona's Blessing](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407531) using her effect.

I am also tempted to conclude that Iona's effect doesn't allow me to block an additional creature during this combat phase, because the block has already taken place before Iona's Blessing was on the battlefield. Is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on both accounts. Of course, if you have multiple combat phases, you could leverage it in the same *turn* but the "hey I just attacked" trigger only happens once, regardless of what the incoming card is capable of doing.

Answer (score 2):

https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Declare_attackers_step

> 508.1. First, the active player declares attackers.
> 508.1m Any abilities that trigger on attackers being declared trigger.

You declare Bruna as an attacker in 508.1, which causes the "Whenever Bruna, Light of Alabaster attacks or blocks, you may attach to it any number of Auras ..." ability to trigger in 508.1m. Ordeal of Thassa isn't attached until after all the attackers are declared, and "When this creature attacks" triggers activate only when an attacker is declared, not from a creature already being an attacker.